# Gettting the index of an element in an array of objects according to a field using regex in MongoDB

Tags: regex, mongodb

Lets say I have the following partial document

```
{ 
  "groups": [
  {
    "text": "Example text 1 blah blah blah",
    "key": 1,
  },
  {
    "text": "Example text 2 blah blah blah",
    "key": 2,
  },
  {
    "text": "Example text 3 blah blah blah",
    "key": 3,
  },
}
```

I would like to search for 'Example text 2' using regex in the text field and retrieve the index of the object.
Basically combination of $indexOfArray and regex, I couldn't find a way to use them together.

What I'm trying to do is to first check if an object with the matching field exists, if it does, change the key value and bump this object to index 0 (first in the array), is there a better way to do this? (I'm planning on swapping the found object index with index 0)

Comment: what if you have 2 matching elements?

Comment: `$regex` function is not available in `$project` stage. So is this a find followed by update to persist the change in db ?

Comment: Hey, the expression is unique between boundaries  ('\\b' + unique_expression + '\\b'). @Veeram, this is a find by text field followed by update to the key field followed by bumping the object to first place in the array. Thanks

Comment: Np. Do you require to l persist the changes to database after updating and bumping ? Or just return updated data from aggregation pipeline ?

Comment: Yes. I need to save it back to the db. It can happen in multiple steps due. I was just wondering if there is a quick way to update the object and also to bump its position. Thanks

Comment: Np. You can do it in two updates. First update find index by regex search and update the key to 0 `db.col.update({_id:someid, "groups.text" :regex condition },{ $set:{ "groups.$.key" : 0 }})` and second update to sort the array `db.col.update({_id:someid}, { $push: { groups: { $each: [ ], $sort: { key: 1 } } } })`